# How to produce accurate UNIX timestamps regardless of server settings when using Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have an application that uses Node.js and I deployed it on a server. I realized that the clock on the server was inaccurate when I tried to use `Date` to get a UNIX timestamp. How can I produce an accurate UNIX timestamp using Node.js if my server is unreliable?

*I'm using this timestamp for scheduling purposes so any solution that produces accurate timestamps in UTC is a solution for this problem.*

Comment: Is the use of the `ntp` protocol in-bounds for you? How "*accurate*" does it have to be? I'm surprised that it's not simpler to just set the time on the server correctly, since dependent on the offset from reality, it may cause issues with authentication and other security mechanisms relying on time-based hashes & such.

Comment: You can probably look into NTP but the best solution is to not have an unreliable server. It means all sorts of things can go wrong - logs might be mismatched, for example, routine tasks might misfire, too. If the time is *variable* then things like daily jobs might not run or run multiple times.

Comment: What's NTP? Also...it seems that the server *knows* the time, but it is in a different timezone. I just learned that `Date` has a  `getTimezoneOffset()` function that will tell me the offset to `UTC`. I never had to deal with timezones up until now, so **TIL** I guess. Now all I have to do is to do `new Date(Date.now().toUTC())` to get a timestamp.

Comment: Wait, you said you wanted the UNIX timestamp and that is an integer representing seconds or milliseconds (how JS defines it), however, *that value is always showing the UTC seconds*. It doesn't have a time zone offset. It's designed to be time zone agnostic, so you read and then transform it as needed. That's what the Date constructor does - the Date object internally holds the date as a UNIX timestamp and also holds the time zone offset, so when you do `getDate()` or `getHour()` etc, it gives you the local value. `Date.now()` ran at the same time would always be the same value on all systems

Comment: And NTP = Network Time Protocol

Comment: `Date.now().toUTC()` is not a thing. `Date.now()` returns a number. There is no `toUTC()` on Date objects, either, nor a static method. There is `Date.UTC()` but it's analogous to the `Date` constructor, just interprets the arguments as UTC, e.g., `new Date(2023, 11, 04, 12, 0)` and `Date.UTC(2023, 11, 04, 12, 0)` would differ by the local time zone offset.

Comment: Wow, I'm totally confused now. How do I get a unix timestamp using `Date` regardless of the timezone of the computer?